# How to use not contains in Sequelize query

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize query for postgrsql db.

I have one field in table, that's type is JSONB. I would like to get data from table like not contain particular value from that field.

For example:
I have field `'field1'` JSONB type.

field1 :[8,10,23] values

No need to fetch particular row, if the `field1` have value 8. Those rows don't have `field1` with 8 i need to fetch those rows.

```
 {
     [Op.not]:{
           field1:
              {
                            
                [Op.contains]: [8]
              }
              }
                 
            }
```

I tried above query but its not getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
     field1:
        {
          [Op.not]:{
                [Op.contains]: [8]
              }
          }
       }
```